# Помогите пожалуйста с кодом в C++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Задание 1

```
 1+1/3!+1/6!+1/9!+…
```

Задание 2

```
 2/4+3/6+4/8+…+10/20
```

вот код к 1 заданию, но выдает не то значение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()     
{
    using namespace std;

    float e, s, i = 1, f = 1, prev;                        
    cin >> e;            
    s = 0;
    do
    {
        s = s + 1/f;
        prev = 1/f;
        i++;
        f = f*i;
        cout << "s=" << s << endl;
    } while (1/f >= e);
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста с этими заданиями, не знаю как реализовать

Comment: @Harry ничего не понял. Можете сделать 1 задание через "while", а второе через "for "?

Comment: `while` *что*? У вас в условии условия завершения нет...

Answer (score 3):

К первому заданию. Поскольку точность вычислений не указана, то просто вычисляем сумму бесконечного ряда. Она равна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что код имеет вид

```
int main() { cout << (exp(3./2.) + 2*cos(sqrt(3)/2))/(3*sqrt(exp(1))) << endl; }
```

Ко второму заданию:

Так как

```
2   3   4         1
- = - = - = ... = -
4   6   8         2
```

и всего имеем 9 таких слагаемых, то искомая программа имеет вид

```
int main() { cout << "9/2 = 4.5\n"; }
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: в первом некрасиво сделано) надо было просто `cout<<"1.16806";`

Comment: @pavel Да, но... Раз в уме посчитать не удалось - значит, надо что-то и машине оставить :)